# Eta-conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Eta-conversion is considering the function `(x) => f(x)` to be the same as the function `f`. While refactoring code at work, I sought to simplify some higher order function call using this equivalence. However, things didn't quite work out, and I'm somewhat lost at what is actually happening, being quite new at Javascript. Here's a minimal example that I hope correctly exemplifies my question.

```
const station = {
  take: (f) => f(5),
  love: function(car) {
    this.take((x) => car.addFuel(x));
  },
  hate: function(car) {
    this.take(car.addFuel);
  }
};

const mercedes = {
  fuel: 0,
  addFuel: function(amount) {
    this.fuel += amount;
  }
};

station.love(mercedes);
console.log(mercedes.fuel);
// output: 5

station.hate(mercedes);
console.log(mercedes.fuel);
// output: 5; expected output: 10
```

From eta equivalence, I expected `love` and `hate` functions from the `station` object to behave the same. However, it seems like the `hate` function actually does nothing. What is happening here?

Comment: I *think* the problem here is the object scope. `love` is wrapped in a arrow function which bevaces diffrent on `this` scope. while `hate` use the `addFuel` function directly which sets the `this` scope to the "station" object. Sorry if i could not explain it properly. english is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a scoping issue of `this`. In your original code in the `hate`callback `this` refers to the global `window` object. You need to use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the correct scope for `this`.

```js
const station = {
  take: (f) => f(5),
  love: function(car) {
    this.take((x) => car.addFuel(x));
  },
  hate: function(car) {
    this.take(car.addFuel.bind(car));
  }
};

const mercedes = {
  fuel: 0,
  addFuel: function(amount) {
    this.fuel += amount;
  }
};

station.love(mercedes);
console.log(mercedes.fuel);

station.hate(mercedes);
console.log(mercedes.fuel);
```

Comment: In the original code, if `this` refers to the window object, then how is it possible that the call to `this.take` works at all? Since there is no `take` function declared in the global namespace.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but i was referring to the `this` in mercedes that refers to `window`

Comment: you can verify by executing your snippet in the console and then typing `window.fuel`, you will have `NaN` as result as you try to sum `5` to `undefined`